# Run flask app on gunicorn,but app can't insert into the db

Tags: database, flask, gunicorn

I am learning Flask by following Miguel Grinberg's "Flask Web Development:
Developing Web Applications with Python." And in Chapter 8：User Authentication, it discusses adding a user registration form to register new users.

When I use Flask's web server to run the app:

```
python manage.py runserver -d -h 0.0.0.0
```

I can register a new account id and use it to login.

But when I use the gunicorn web server to run the app:

```
gunicorn manage:app
```

When I register a new account id, without any hints after submission, and use the new account id to login, the account id does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:use the Postgresql instead of SQLite